# How to send data from Android to server and from server to Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app. How to send data from app to server and then server automatically send data to next app?

Comment: Write the code for it, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: Sir main reson is that i am not getting any logic in my mind for this i have tried lot at internet but all in vain if you have any link than i would be very thankful to you for this favour

Comment: My basic aim is that when a user press at map it give user name and skill to customer now if he want to book that person than he pree book button and in reward of this i want that request goes to that person. but i am not getting it

Answer (score 2):

you can create a web service on the server side and call it from android client to send and recieve data, or you write a servlet.

A [web service](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-web-service) is a standard for exchanging information between different types of applications irrespective of language and platform. For example, an android application can interact with java or .net application using web services.

Example on Android side:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    String registrationUrl = String.format("http://myserver/register?id=%s&name=%s", myId, URLEncoder.encode(myName,"UTF-8"));
    url = new URL(registrationUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "Registration success");
    } else {
        Log.w("MyApp", "Registration failed for: " + registrationUrl);              
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Volley library for networking related operations inside your android application. It'll be pretty easier for you to use.
Try this link to learn the basics: 
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

For server side operation you need to create a web service.